Calling the world's simplest NASM function from C - segfault
I'm trying to learn x86-64 assembly on linux, using NASM with gcc. I've made just about the simplest conceivable assembly function which should do nothing other than return 0. This is corr.asm:
global corr
default rel

section .text:
corr:
    mov rax, 0
    ret

Then I have a C file with code to call this function and print its return value. This is test.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern int64_t corr(void);

int main(void) {
    int64_t x = corr();

    printf("Result: %u\n", x);

    return 0;
}

Finally, I compile it into an executable and run it like so:
nasm -f elf64 -o corr.o corr.asm
gcc -c -o test.o test.c
gcc corr.o test.o -o test
./test

Unfortunately even a hurdle as low as this apparently presents a tripping hazard, in the form of an immediate segfault and no output. I've tried removing default rel, removing extern, and removing both. I've tried single-stepping instructions in gdb, but all that tells me is that it segfaults on the call instruction as it tries to enter my function, and that's exactly as confusing to me as this already was. The segfault persists even without mov rax, 0.
I've looked around for examples of people calling NASM x86-64 functions from C, and I found a few. For example https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2021/cmsc430/a86.html shows essentially the exact same commands to build an executable, and their assembly function differs only in that it actually does something worthwhile. I can't see why theirs should work and mine should not.

Drop colon from section .text:, it is parsed as part of the section name so you get a non-executable custom section rather than the default for .text

Damn. I thought it would probably be something about as embarrassing as that. Nice catch, thanks.

Unrelated, but %u isn't the right format specifier for int64_t.

I reported this to the NASM bug tracker at https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392927

In the manual the relevant part is at https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.16.03/html/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.9.2 and it lists noexec as the default for any section name other than .text where the other entry is applicable to .text:

ecm's comment is absolutely right - if I write section .text without the colon it works fine and prints Result: 0. A totally silent "error" until the program is run.
